# Include a C# (.cs) file in my XSL file so I can use intellisense?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Right now I can include C# code just fine in my XSLT file and I am referencing it with no problems throughout the XSLT file.

XSLT FILE:

```
<xsl:import href="secondXSLFile.xsl" />
```

XSLT FILE (secondXSLFile.xsl) with C# code:

```
<msxsl:script implements-prefix="myCode" language="C#">
<![CDATA[
   public string ACoolFunction(string str1, string str2)
   { //some code }
]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

However, when I am in visual studio and I am editing C# code in that 2nd XSLT file up above, I do not get intellisense in the code. So, my question is this: Is it possible to reference an actual .cs file in the first XSLT up above rather than referencing the second XSLT file? That way I can have my .cs file opened up in visual studio and just work with it in there. It will be a very big file with lots of functions, so this will be much easier.

Or, if there is a way to simply get intellisense within that msxsl:script block then that would do just fine for my purposes, too!

Thanks for any help!

Quick Edit: I am basically wondering if I could do something like this:

```
<xsl:import href="mycode.cs" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that `XslCompiledTransform` has another mechanism to call .NET code, namely [extension objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf741884%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? You would then write C# or VB code files, compile them in your IDE and pass an instance or a static class to the `XslCompiledTransform` `Transform` method, using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. That way you can separate C# and XSLT code. As you mention ASP.NET I have to point out that the ASP.NET `xml` control uses `XslTransform`, not `XslCompiledTransform, so depending on how you exactly use XSLT in ASP.NET you need to check a different API than the one I linked to.

Comment: I accidentally tagged asp.net without thinking. This is very much a large backend project that iterates through many xsl files and creates many individual xml files. I am new to this, but I am seeing tons of repetitive code as well as ugly, long-winded xpath code that I want to make prettier and, hopefully, more efficient via C#. All that being said, I was not aware of what you just said. I have not even seen the code that fires off all of these xsl files. It sounds like, from what you are saying, that I should go find out how this thing really gets driven and then dig into that app?

Comment: @RandyWhirl, yes, check how XSLT is being executed, normally you would use `XslCompiledTransform` to do this, and there you have the option to use extension objects instead of `ms:script` to call your .NET code.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer even though it is the only answer, thank you! I went and did some digging around and found the app that drives this whole process. Got the code for it. In there, I see very clearly the few lines of code that call the XSL files in a for loop. This is where I am going to be adding the code in the examples that you linked me to so that I can pass in a class to the XSL and allow it to leverage that functionality. Thank you!

Comment: It seems this answer is not helpful if you cannot access or change the code that invokes the XSL transformation. However, in that case, it should *still* be possible to use an `<msxsl:assembly>` element to reference a DLL of your own with reusable code.